# Making a responsive site with divs that create two columns on homepage

Tags: responsive-design

Is is possible to program my site in such a way that these two columns of posts on the homepage will also display as two columns on a smart phone? I'm using a twenty twelve child theme, which is a responsive theme, but the code I used to create the two columns of posts is pretty elementary, so it's just combining into one column on a smart phone.

below is an excerpt of code from my index.php that shows the way i'm creating the two columns. these divs also correspond with simple CSS in my style.css file

i'd gladly take a different approach to creating the columns if it allows them to show as two independent columns on a smart phone as well.

the site is at: internalcompass.us/castle if you want to look at the page

thanks

```
</div>
<div id="right-column">
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query('category_name=favorites');
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
  $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID ?>
  <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
<div id="left-column">
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query('category_name=Recents');
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
  $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID ?>
  <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: The look of the page is controlled by the css rules. The code you show does not create a look by itself. You have to edit the theme.

Comment: thanks, @whistletoe. some of the CSS edits for computer or ipad display don't translate directly to the smart phone, so that's exactly the question. are there CSS edits that i can make that will allow both of my columns to show up on the iphone side by side instead of as one single column? matt, below, gave a great piece of guidance, but it still doesn't affect the iphone display.

Comment: Well, the css for the theme has rules to change the number of columns based on the width of the viewport. You can see this if you resize the browser window on a desktop computer. Locate the css file(s) for the theme and find where it specifies column width and float. A tip can be to look for "@media" expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your right-column and left-column from a width of 270px to a width of 50%. Then when your window is above 600pixels (most modern phones), you'll still see two columns.

I.e. edit **your** style.css (not the main theme style.css) and change:

```
div#left-column {
    width: 270px;
    float: left;
    clear: none;
    }
div#right-column {
    width: 270px;
    float: right;
    clear: none;
    }
```

to:

```
div#left-column {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    clear: none;
    }
div#right-column {
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
    clear: none;
    }
```

though you may want to add a little padding/margin room after doing this.

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: oh, boo. the 50% edit actually only addresses the issue on an ipad (which is great -thank you). but on an iphone, i still get one single column displaying. i wonder why. that seemed like the right advice. anyway, if anyone has another bit of info to chime in, let me know!

Comment: On the iPhone it becomes a different problem where you need to address the viewport size and change the responsive design not to drop down to one column at such a low resolution. But I'm not sure anything you show in those will be readable on the iPhone if they are still two columns, the text will be very small. Still, if you want to do it, you can change your media queries...

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the info very much!